# Xcode ios Unknown type name?

Tags: ios, xcode, class, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I have a question about the following error "`Unknown type name VistaDereIzq`"

I have a view called `VistaDereIzq`. And I do the following to add that view in this view.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "VistaDereIzq.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface VistaNavegador : UIViewController  <UIWebViewDelegate>
{ 
    VistaDereIzq *VistaIzq2;   <----- "Unknown type name VistaDereIzq"
}

@end
```

Comment: That would seem to imply that `VistaDereIzq.h` somehow isn't properly declaring the class — can you show us that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You probably have a circular dependency/include. Use a forward declaration (`@class MONClass;`)  rather than `#import`ing the header. Since there is no physical dependence, you should be using a forward declaration in the first place (i.e. for much faster builds).

So instead of:

```
#import "VistaDereIzq.h"
```

use:

```
@class VistaDereIzq;
```

and then add your `#import` to an `.m` file as needed.

Comment: Yes Indeed, "You probably have a circular dependency/include" Removed the offending other #include.  Thanks!